# How to reverse serializers like models in ForeignKey?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='product')

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    sub_category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sub_category_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='sub_category_img')
```

In serializers:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['url', 'id', 'name', 'price', 'sub_category']   

class SubCategorySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    product = ProductSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SubCategory
        fields = ['url', 'id', 'sub_category_name', 'sub_category_img', 'product']
```

Using models, I can get access to `Products.sub_category` for a single queryset and also `SubCategory.product` reverse query using related_name in ForeignKey.

Using serializers, I can get access the `ProductSerializer` queryset using `SubCategorySerializer` but can't access `SubCategorySerializer` from `ProductSerializer`. I only get the url for `sub_category` when use `ProductSerializer`.

How can i reverse both in api endpoints?

**I tried, in serializers,**

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    sub = SubCategorySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['url', 'id', 'name', 'price', 'sub_category', 'sub']   

class SubCategorySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    product = ProductSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SubCategory
        fields = ['url', 'id', 'sub_category_name', 'sub_category_img', 'product']
```

It's not working. How can I get both queryset like models?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    sub_category = SubCategorySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['url', 'id', 'name', 'price', 'sub_category']
```

Or just use [**`depth=1`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) in Product Serializer:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['url', 'id', 'name', 'price', 'sub_category'] 
        depth = 1
```